# Not getting the check box event after click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not getting the checked status of a checkbox. Checks are dynamically created.
Below is the code:

```
'[id^=taskcheckbox_] click' : function(el){
    var taskObj={};
    var taskCheckBoxId = el.attr("id");
    var indexOfTask = taskCheckBoxId.split("_")[2];
    var checkedValue = this.element.find("#"+taskCheckBoxId).attr("checked");
    var task_id = taskCheckBoxId.split("_")[1];
    if(checkedValue == "checked" && checkedValue != undefined){
        this.count++;
}}
```

Control is not going in `if` condition after the check box is checked.
Value of `checkedValue` is always coming as `undefined`.

Comment: It will be great if you add your HTML also

Comment: isn't `this.element.find("#"+taskCheckBoxId)` the same as `el` since your code implies that they share the same `id` (*the `taskCheckBoxId` is the `id` attribute of `el`*).

Comment: Hi  Gaby aka G. Petrioli, I just thought about your point..and it worked by using the below: var checkedValue = el.prop("checked");

Answer (score 3):

> Use prop() instead of attr()

►If you're using jQuery 1.6 or later, use prop() instead of attr()

```
var checkedValue = this.element.find("#"+taskCheckBoxId).prop("checked");
```

When you are using `prop()`, the value returned will be Boolean

```
$(document).delegate("[id^=taskcheckbox_]", "click", function(el) {
  //[id^=taskcheckbox_] click' : function(el){
  var taskObj = {};
  var taskCheckBoxId = el.currentTarget.id;
  var indexOfTask = taskCheckBoxId.split("_")[2];
  var checkedValue = $(el.currentTarget).is(":checked");
  var task_id = taskCheckBoxId.split("_")[1];
  if (checkedValue) {
    console.log('checked')
      //this.count++;
  }
})
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/75sttmxj/4/)

Comment: @Raj Add your HTML to the question. That will be really helpful

Comment: @Raj I have updated my code. Please verify and let me know if it doesnot work

Comment: <tr id="row_53" class="scp-odd"><td class="scp-column-even scp-column-first scp-c-list-c scp-first">
        <label for="taskcheckbox_24/02/2016_53" class="scp-label   radio-check-label"></label>
        <input class="scp-input-check   checkbox_selector" type="checkbox" name="" id="taskcheckbox_24/02/2016_53">
        </td>
        </tr>

Comment: @Raj I have added a demo fiddle. It is working. Please check

Comment: Thanks Rino Raj for your effort....It worked with : var checkedValue = el.prop("checked");